# My cat hasn't pooped in two days what should i do.

Tags: cats, defecation

He is a male cat, neutered, 20 years old. The other cat is male, neutered, 10 years old. They are both still eating, drinking and peeing, just not pooping. I started them on some new soft food, could that be the reason

Comment: Welcome to pets.se Robert! I have linked questions similar to yours, please have a look at the answers provided :)